# How much user email add firebase auth

Tags: firebase-authentication

If i use firebase auth for authentication, how much number of user data (number of row) add in this firebase app.
Plz anyone can explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default registering a user in Firebase Authentication doesn't create any data in the database of your project. If such data *is* being created, it's being done so by code in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to know more about the Firebase auth [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits).

The most basic ones are that there are 100 milion anonymous accounts awailable per project but the normal users are unlimited. Check out the link above for more info about the auth limitations.

Comment: When user signup success, then user signup data store in firebase db. So i am free user of firebase auth. How much (maximum number)  signup data (rows data) store for any project?

Comment: Sorry. I don't get what you are asking for. Can you pls explain it a little bit more.

Comment: When using a small project  like as use max. 10000 person,  use my project but this project authentication process use firebase auth (free tier).  This free use of firebase auth is enough for store user data???

Comment: If i use free firebase Authentication for my project,  how much user auth data store firebase auth freely.

Comment: You can have unlimited auth data for normal users. If you want to store extra data to one of the firebase databases there are other limits. But all auth data is free for unlimited amount of users.

Answer (score 0):

The Queries that you wrote in the function are good to go, and you may also be able to add values in the Schools list, However, the reason you are getting this error is because **_fetchSchoolList()** method is not returning anything,

to resolve this you can:

1. Return a list that would contain the desired elements from the firestore

   ```
   CollectionReference SchoolList = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ListSchools');

   List<dynamic> Schools = [];
    _fetchSchoolList() async{
    List<dynamic> temp_list = [];
    DocumentSnapshot result = await 
    SchoolList.doc('List').get().then((value) {
    temp_list.add(value);
    });
    return temp_list;
    }
   ```
2. Then, you can store that list in Schools list and then use that list for further functionalities

   Schools = await _fetchSchoolList();

Also, do not forget to use async keyword whenever you need to use await